# SqlAlchemy: UPDATE and INSERT order wrong with foreign key to self

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a table which has a foreign key relationship with itself (on a compound primary key)

E.g. something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE graph (
  start_id character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  end_id character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  weight integer,
  other_start_id character varying(50),
  other_end_id character varying(50),
  CONSTRAINT graph_pkey PRIMARY KEY (start_id, end_id),
  CONSTRAINT graph_other FOREIGN KEY (other_start_id, other_end_id)
     REFERENCES graph (start_id, end_id) MATCH SIMPLE
     ON UPDATE SET NULL ON DELETE SET NULL,
)
```

In SqlAlchemy, I create a new (pending) graph object 'new_obj', and assign it to the other attribute of an existing persistent object, i.e.:

```
exist_obj.other = new_obj
```

When I commit the session, SqlAlchemy issues the UPDATE on the existing object before it issues the INSERT to create the new_obj.  My database rightly complains on the UPDATE that it can't find the foreign key `graph_other` (as new_obj hasn't been inserted yet).

I thought SqlAlchemy was supposed to be smart about the ordering of SQL?
I'm using version 0.5.4

Is there a way of manually ordering the operations?

Comment: Could you show a little more of your code? It would be useful to see everything between (and including) the object creation and the commit.

Comment: @Ian Yes this is a bit light - will try to extract a minimal reproducible sequence from the much larger codebase that this occurs in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this question is quite old and the OP likely lost interest, it has an answer in the current 0.7 version of SA. The documentation has a [section discussing special cases of Many-to-Many relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html#self-referential-many-to-many-relationship) that includes a simple graph Node example using the ORM.

The OP's specific question was how to control the order of `INSERT` and `UPDATE` for those cases where the new elements point to one another. The [SA docs provide examples here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html#rows-that-point-to-themselves-mutually-dependent-rows) for handling this kind of problem with Mutually-Dependent rows:

> To enable the usage of a supplementary UPDATE statement, we use the
>   post_update option of relationship(). This specifies that the linkage
>   between the two rows should be created using an UPDATE statement after
>   both rows have been INSERTED

Comment: Have lost interest, but your answer seems plausible!